# Strings Dictionary with dynamic units

Tags: swift, swiftui

I would like to dynamically specify the unit to be used (e.g. hours, minutes, seconds) in the Strings Dictionary when called:

```
Text("\(unit) \(value))", tableName: "SingularAndPlural")
```

- `unit` contains the unit as a string
- `value` contains the value as an integer

[image: Strings Dictionary]

But that doesn't work, it doesn't resolve.

I've tried all possible variants, but I can't get any further.

Comment: Have you considered using the built in number formatted? It already has locale-aware unit selection and localized strings built-in

Comment: No I have not. Is singular and plural with number formatted possible? In different Languages the unit is leading or trailing.

Comment: Yep, absolutely! You're right to be concerned about singular vs. plural spelling, leading vs. trailing units, etc. There are all sorts of things we take for granted that vary wildly by region (some other examples: whether zero is singular or plural, if there is a space between the currency and number or not, using a dot vs comma for the decimal separator, how digits are grouped, grouping with commas vs spaces, etc). Correct internationalization was an important enough priority for Apple that they built-in quite a few tools for it (look at all the `*Formatter` types provided by the iOS SDK).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use `stringsDict` you should probably use localisation provided by the built-in Formatters. In this case `DateComponentsFormatter` probably does what you need:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(["en", "ru", "el", "th"], id: \.self) { localeId in
                Section(localeId) {
                    ForEach(0..<3, id: \.self) { i in
                        HStack {
                            Text(formatter(localeId).string(from: DateComponents(minute: i))!)
                            Spacer()
                            Text(formatter(localeId).string(from: DateComponents(second: i))!)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
            
    func formatter(_ localeId: String) -> DateComponentsFormatter {
        var calendar = Calendar.current
        calendar.locale = Locale(identifier: localeId)
        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        formatter.calendar = calendar
        formatter.unitsStyle = .full
        return formatter
    }
}
```

[image]

It's even simpler if you just want to format for the device's current locale:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0..<3, id: \.self) { i in
                HStack {
                    Text(DateComponents(minute: i), formatter: Self.formatter)
                    Spacer()
                    Text(DateComponents(second: i), formatter: Self.formatter)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    static var formatter: DateComponentsFormatter {
        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        formatter.unitsStyle = .full
        return formatter
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the example was poorly chosen.
I need this for everything, e.g. incorrect entries, characters, entries, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "incorrect entries, characters, entries, etc."? What's an "entry" or "character" in this context?

Comment: I want to provide a picker with data dynamically, not only related to time formats. So also, for example, a property "Entries in register" with "no entry", "1 entry" ... "24 entries" or another property "Books to Read" with "No Book", "1 Book" ... "10 Books".

Comment: Doesn't anyone have an idea how to solve this using strings dictionary? I just can't get any further.